# My component is trying to access data that doesn't exist yet, "Cannot read property 'data' of undefined"

Tags: reactjs, redux, state

My Component that is trying to mapStateToProps some form data that doesn't exist until the user inputs and submits. The form would take the inputs, store it into redux and then I would be able to take that data and populate a table after an API call

```
const StepOne = props => {
  const [formObj, setFormObj] = useState({
    rigName: "",
    desc: "",
    choices: [
      {
        choice: "",
        customAttribute: ""
      }
    ]
  });

  return (
    some inputs fields
  );
};
const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    formData: state.stepOneForm.data
  };
};
const mapDisptachToProps = disptach => {
  return {
    addFormIntoRedux: data => disptach(AddFormData(data))
  };
};
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDisptachToProps)(StepOne);
```

I've found other posts suggesting I include initial data? or having a check after the render, but I'm not sure what that would look like.
I believe these options could be the solution, but not sure how to move from here.

[You can see the error here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ClIwv.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is could solve your problem:

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    formData: state.stepOneForm ? state.stepOneForm.data : null,
  };
};
```

I'm using `null` as the default value for the case where `stepOneForm` in undefined, but you can change that to your needs.